# Blank window using Javafx

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I made a window by using the screen builder program, but after I run it, only a white blank window appears. I think the problem that all variables , which are lblOUTPUT, aren't assigned. I'm a beginner at Scene builder and have been really struggling with this issue because it's my first work.

FXmain

```
    package javaapplication6;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author ammar
 */
public class FXMain extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/javaapplication6/FXML.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Kilometer to miles converter");

    stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

FXMLcontroller:

```
    enter code here
package javaapplication6;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author ammar
 */
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label lblOUTPUT;
    @FXML
    private Button btnCONVERT;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtKm;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I solved after two hours of struggling, I just click the run button in the NetBeans (looks like a play button) and after that, right-click on the main class, then run the file, and it worked!.